# word for someone who is a "victim" of confirmation bias or a logical fallacy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, for example, Jim has his bias confirmed on some argument. Is there a noun that describes his relation to the confirmation bias?

Victim is the first word that comes to mind for me, but it  gives a weird connotation in my opinion (feels like too strong of a word).

I feel like this could extend to someone that commits a logical fallacy too.

example:

Jim believes that women can not be president of the United States. He references a statistic that of the 44 presidents, none of them are women. Jim is a *victim* of confirmation bias.

Comment: Being in the wrong place, at the wrong time, with the wrong people.

Comment: I was thinking "patsy" or "chump", but those are pretty strong words as well.

Comment: How about "fallacee"?

Comment: By victim, I thought you meant someone who is affected by an error made because of a bias or fallacy. But you mean the one who made such an error, right?

Comment: Jim has *fallen prey to* confirmation bias.

Comment: You could say he has anosognosia.

Comment: Jim's conclusion suffers from confirmation bias.

Comment: Jim **relies on** confirmation bias.

Answer (score 1):

The biological sense of "host" could work figuratively, as being "an organism that harbors a parasite, or ..., typically providing nourishment and shelter."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_%28biology%29

> Jim is a host for many specious biases.

(By the way, a bias may be reinforced by or be consistent with, but not be *confirmed* by, a result. What might be confirmed is that Jim is biased.)

Comment: In context, this wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your example sentence, *victim* works quite well. It connotes that someone has unknowingly, and to their own detriment, engaged in the confirmation bias fallacy.

However, if you don't want that victim connotation, there's a common English idiom to describe this relationship as well: *to preach to the choir* means to make an argument to an audience that has already adopted the conclusion of that argument. In this situation, Jim could possibly be *a member of the choir* (though I just made that expression up, and it would only be understood by reference to the idiom).

Answer (score -1):

I think 'perpetrator' would work.

Comment: A *perpetrator* is a person who has committed a crime. Engaging in a fallacy is not generally a crime, and in this example, the person is in fact receiving the effect of the fallacy, not inflicting it on someone else.